# Different records at different Nameservers

Tags: domain-name-system, routing, hosting, a-record

At my domains registrar I have set up two name servers.
They look like this:

```
NS1: xx123456.ip-11-111-111.eu.
NS2: ns1.XX.net.
```

I know that first one is quite strange but I cannot do anything about it.

On hosting provider that owns those name servers I changed DNS records to point some IP for different provider (location of new website).

The problem is that some of users see new version of website (minority) but most of them see old one (about 70%).

I used this website: http://viewdns.info/ and I got interesting report that contains following errors:

> Oops! Your name servers don't all seem to have identical NS records for your domain. This could lead to some visitors not being able to see your site (or seeing it on a different server)! This should be fixed ASAP!

and

> Oops! It appears that the following nameserves listed at your local servers are not listed at the parent servers:
>
> zzz2.yyy.net.
>
> You should ensure that these nameservers are valid and working. If they are not, you will encounter connectivity issues with your domain.

and

> Oops! It appears that the following nameserves listed at the parent servers are not listed at your local servers:
>
> ns1.XX.net.  **(please note it's the same that is set at domain registrar)**
>
> You should ensure that these nameservers are valid and working. If they aren't, it can cause odd behaviour including some people not being able to access your domain.

I understand first one that NS's have different records for my domain and it causes misrouting of some users.

I don't understand other two. Can you please try helping me in figuring out how can I fix this issue so all users see new version of website?

This is Parallels Plesk panel on hosting provider side.

As asked - the domain name I am asking about is uszyjmimamo.pl

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to include the domain you're asking about.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned you have nameservers with two different providers:

```
$ whois uszyjmimamo.pl

DOMAIN NAME:           uszyjmimamo.pl
registrant type:       individual
nameservers:           ns1.he.net.
                       ns3022609.ip-51-254-199.eu.
```

Is that intentional? That alone isn't a problem, but it makes things more difficult to manage, as your records need to be updated in two places. As you'll see, that is the problem your facing right now - your DNS records do not match between your two DNS providers. Let's look up your domain at both nameservers.

```
$ dig uszyjmimamo.pl @ns1.he.net +short
51.254.199.92

$ dig uszyjmimamo.pl @ns3022609.ip-51-254-199.eu +short
91.185.184.249
```

As you can see, they have two different records for your zone apex. You need to sign into the management for one of those and correct the record so that they match.

One additional problem is that your `NS` records are incorrect. These should point to the nameserver records as specified at your domain registrar:

```
$ dig NS uszyjmimamo.pl @ns1.he.net +short
ns5.he.net.
ns2.he.net.
ns4.he.net.
ns1.he.net.
ns3.he.net.

$ dig NS uszyjmimamo.pl @ns3022609.ip-51-254-199.eu +short
ns3022609.ip-51-254-199.eu.
sdns2.ovh.net.
```

I'll give a couple of recommendations. First, unless you have a good reason for maintaining two DNS providers, do away with that situation, as it's only making things more difficult for you. After that, read up on DNS and how everything works. By doing so, you'll be able to diagnose and fix this type of issue on your own.

Comment: You even caught the `NS` record mismatch that I started to robo-comment. *I am obsolete.*

Comment: Using two or more providers can make sense in order to achieve redundancy. But when doing so I would recommend keeping the zone file in source control and upload the full zone files to each provider such that they are always in sync. Not all providers support that mode of operation though.

Comment: @kasperd Yep, agreed. In this case though, it seems the OP doesn't have the expertise to manage such a system, which is why I recommended simplifying things.

Comment: Thank you for your vast answer. It cleared me a lot. Indeed I don't have expertise here. I am developer and I encountered this situation on my customers environment and I am not in power to change any of this.

Comment: Then your employer needs to **spend actual money** and buy in expertise that does know how to run a setup like this.

Comment: I used other (new hosting's) Name Servers and MXed mail to his old server (which was the key). Everything is working fine. This was the only way to get around this I think.

BTW. If I want to hire expert on this, who should I hire? Admin? Cause I think that not necesarily developer (which is actually me, and I have limited experience with this).

Comment: Any experienced sysadmin (like myself or MadHatter) would be able to help out with this sort of thing.